# Filesystemwatcher file created event not decompressing files

Tags: powershell

I got a simple script that should watch for new files in specified folder and uncompress them on arriving. Simple, but my script only works under the debugger of Powershell ISE. When outside the debugger, on file creation it only prints "New file xxx found" and "Done", without decompressing it, nor deleting, but also no errors. I'm I missing something here?

```
# Folder you to monitor
$PathToMonitor = "C:\tmp1".
$OutputPath = "C:\tmp"
$Filter = "*.zip"  # Filter for zip files.

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter = $Filter

# make sure the watcher emits events
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# define the code that should execute when a file change is detected
$Action = {
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    try
    {
        Write-Host "New file " + $FullPath + " found"
        $TarProgram = "tar.exe"
        $TarArgs = 'xvf "' + $FullPath + '" -C ' + $OutputPath
        Start-Process $TarProgram $TarArgs -Wait -WindowStyle hidden
        Remove-Item -Path $FullPath -Force
        Write-Host "Done"
    }
    catch [System.SystemException]
    {
        Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
    }
}

# add event handlers
$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreateFtpGe
}

Write-Host "Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor"

try
{
    do
    {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 10
    } while ($true)
}
catch [System.SystemException]
{
    Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
}
finally
{
    # this gets executed when user presses CTRL+C
    # remove the event handlers
    Write-Host "Cleaning up"
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreateFtpGe
    # remove background jobs
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    # remove filesystemwatcher
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    "Event Handler disabled."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, I found the issue. It's somehow related to variables scopes in Powershell. 
If instead of using a variable declared at the begin of the script to hold the value of $OutputPath I use a literal string then it works. Otherwise, it complains that the value is null at runtime (In Powershell ISE it shows a value)

So, the action block now looks like this:

```
$Action = {
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    try
    {
        Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $FullPath -DestinationPath "C:\Temp"
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$FullPath" -Force
    }
    catch [System.SystemException]
    {
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

I would prefer to have all my vars at the begin, so they can be easily changed if needed, but at least this version works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a period here...

```
$PathToMonitor = "C:\tmp1".
```

...that is invalid syntax and the script should fail anyway. Yet, that could be just a type you did on posting here.

Why are you using tar vs the PowerShell built-in archive cmdlets?

if tar.exe is not in your PowerShell or system paths, you have to fully qualify that path to it for it to be used.

$TarProgram = 'C:\ProgramFiles\tar.exe'

So, your code should work in any PowerShell host (ISE [in/out of debug mode])/powershell.exe/VSCode, et al. AS I just tested it. Yet again, the cmdlets are there. Example of the below running in the new Windows Terminal.

```
#region Begin Script

# Folder you to monitor
$PathToMonitor = 'D:\tmp1'
$OutputPath    = 'D:\tmp'
$Filter        = '*.zip'  # Filter for zip files.

$FileSystemWatcher        = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path   = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter = $Filter

# make sure the watcher emits events
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# define the code that should execute when a file change is detected
$Action = {
    $details   = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $FullPath  = $details.FullPath
    $OldName   = $details.OldName
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated

    try
    {
        "New file $FullPath  found"
        Expand-Archive -Path $FullPath -DestinationPath 'D:\tmp'

        # Start-Process $TarProgram $TarArgs -Wait -WindowStyle hidden
        Remove-Item -Path $FullPath -Force

        'Done'
    }
    catch [System.SystemException]
    {$PSItem.ScriptStackTrace}
}

# add event handlers
$handlers = . {
    $RegisterObjectEventSplat = @{
        InputObject      = $FileSystemWatcher
        EventName        = 'Created'
        Action           = $Action
        SourceIdentifier = 'FSCreateFtpGe'
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent @RegisterObjectEventSplat
}

"Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor"

try
{
    do { Wait-Event -Timeout 10 } 
    while ($true)
}
catch [System.SystemException]
{$_.ScriptStackTrace}
finally
{
    <#
    this gets executed when user presses CTRL+C
    remove the event handlers
    #>
    'Cleaning up'
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreateFtpGe

    # remove background jobs
    $handlers | 
    Remove-Job

    # remove filesystemwatcher
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    'Event Handler disabled.'
}

#endregion End Script


# Results

 Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property Caption, Version

Caption                  Version
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.752}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp' -Verbose
 (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp').Count
0
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp1' -Verbose
 (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp1').Count
0
 .\FSWCopyUnzip.ps1
Watching for changes to D:\tmp1
New file D:\tmp1\book1.zip  found
Done
Cleaning up

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp' -Verbose


    Directory: D:\tmp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        13-Mar-20     12:19             70 abc.txt
-a----        13-Mar-20     22:27             71 book1.txt
-a----        06-Apr-20     21:51           2979 Data.zip
-a----        04-Mar-20     01:04             72 FileWithLines.txt


 Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp1' -Verbose
 (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\tmp1').Count
 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The period is wrong, but it's not the real path I'm using, I was a typo when I was posting the question.I switched to tar because I was getting mad trying to understand why it didn't work. I just tested your version, it doesn't work either, so it should be something in my pc..

Comment: NO worries, as noted you see that this works as expected on my system. So, sure, possibly environmental on your side, but I really cannot imagine what you be blocking unzipping stuff. It's just a file system action.